# Parse text from this webpage in bash

Tags: regex, bash, parsing, curl, sed

I want to write a bash script that can parse the version number of apps in the android appstore. For example this app, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alphonso.pulse&hl=en

How would I get the value '3.0.6' from the Current Version header on the right hand side of the page?

Comment: Here is the xpath to the `3.0.6`:  `//*[@id="details-tab-1"]/div[1]/dl/dd[3]`.  You'll need to find a way to parse out the webpage, and [regex is not your friend](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529339) with html parsing.

Comment: What if I wget the page? I could then match this line right? `Current Version:</dt><dd itemprop="softwareVersion">3.0.6</dd>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ site=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alphonso.pulse

$ curl -s $site | sed -rn 's/.*(Current Version:)[^0-9]*([0-9.]+).*/\1\2/p'
Current Version:3.0.6 

$ curl -s $site | sed -rn 's/.*Current Version:[^0-9]*([0-9.]+).*/\1/p'
3.0.6
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. I get `sed: 1: "s/.*(Current Version:)[ ...": \1 not defined in the RE` followed by lots of html

Comment: I'm guessing you are running `OSX` then, try `sed -En 's/.*(Current Version:)[^0-9]*([0-9.]+).*/\1\2/p'` instead.

Comment: If I wanted to exclude "Current Version:" how would I modify it? Sorry..haven't used sed in a while.

Comment: Here you go `sed -rn 's/.*Current Version:[^0-9]*([0-9.]+).*/\1/p'` I'd appreciate a +1.